# AJAX Chaining - AJAX a page that is using AJAX

Tags: ajax

I have a page, update.php. I want it to use ajax to load a page that is doing a bunch of calculations on it, appraisal.php.

appraisal.php has ajax commands in it that update a database once the calculations finish. It has a setTimeout(function()) on it, if that matters.

I made a test button on update.php to open the appraisal.php page in a new window with the info I'm putting in my update.php ajax command and it works fine, the database updates. But if I try to call the appraisal.php page with the ajax command from update.php, the database doesn't change. The 'success: function' is returning true.

I have tried testing an UPDATE sql command on the appraisal.php itself from the update.php ajax and that works, so I know the variables in the update.php ajax statement are correct.

Is it a problem with chaining ajax commands?

**update_apprasials.php AJAX** (Loads view_appraisal.php but isn't triggering updateAppraisal function, $updateSQL test code is running)

```
function updateAppraisal( appraisalID, counter ) {
$.ajax(
   {
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'view_appraisal.php',
      data: { 
        "id": appraisalID,
        "updateAppraisal": "Yes"
      },
      success: function (response) {
        console.log ('Appraisal '+ appraisalID +' Updated');
        $(".update_status").append(counter + '. Appraisal '+ appraisalID +' Updated</br>');
      },
      error: function () {
        console.log ('Appraisal '+ appraisalID +' Error');
        $(".update_status").append(counter + '. Appraisal '+ appraisalID +' <span style=\"color:#b8212d\"><strong>Error</strong></span></br>');
      }
   }
); 
}
```

Console log print out: 'Appraisal 108_20230821113149 Updated'

**update_appraisals.php Button for Testing Purposes** (opens view_appraisal.php with the same variables as the ajax command in a new window. When the page opens, it does what it's supposed to and runs the updateAppraisal function, as well as the $updateSQL test code)

```
<form class='form-horizontal' target='_blank' action='view_appraisal.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='hidden' id='id' name='id' value='108_20230821113149'></input>
    <input type='hidden' id='updateAppraisal' name='updateAppraisal' value='Yes'></input>
<button type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' class='w-100 btn btn-lg btn-success' style='margin-top:10px' data-loading-text='Loading...'>Test Appraisals</button>
</form>
```

**view_appraisal.php**

```
function updateAppraisal(id){
    
    setTimeout(function() { 
        let Other_Costs = document.getElementById( 'other_costs' ).value;
        let Appraised_Value = document.getElementById( 'selling_price' ).value;
        let Subtotal = document.getElementById( 'subtotal' ).value;
        let Sugg_Book_Cost = document.getElementById( 'book_cost' ).value;
        
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onload = function () {
        }

        xhttp.open( "GET", "update_appraisals_ajax.php?id=" + id + "&other_costs=" + Other_Costs + "&appraised_value=" + Appraised_Value + "&subtotal=" + Subtotal + "&sugg_book_cost=" + Sugg_Book_Cost, true );
        xhttp.send();
    }, 1000);
    
}

if (isset($_POST['updateAppraisal'])){
    echo "Update Appraisal is set. <script> updateAppraisal(`$appraisal_id`);</script>";
    $updateSQL = mysqli_query( $con, "UPDATE Appraisals SET Hours = '300-' WHERE Appraisal_ID = '$appraisal_id'" )or die( mysqli_error() );
}
```

**update_appraisals_ajax.php**

```
$appraisal_id = $_GET[ 'id' ];

$other_costs = $_GET[ 'other_costs' ];
$appraised_value = $_GET[ 'appraised_value' ];
$subtotal = $_GET[ 'subtotal' ];
$sugg_book_cost = $_GET[ 'sugg_book_cost' ];

$updateSQL = mysqli_query( $con, "UPDATE Appraisals SET Other_Costs = '$other_costs', Appraised_Value ='$appraised_value', Subtotal = '$subtotal', Sugg_Book_Cost = '$sugg_book_cost'  WHERE Appraisal_ID = '$appraisal_id'" )or die( mysqli_error() );
```

Comment: Did you returned anything from appraisal.php after your database update? add the codes to your question.

Comment: @Saroj - I've added the relevant code. I just need the ajax off of the view_appraisal.php page to submit the database update. I've had to go this route because view_appraisal.php is doing a lot of calculations after the page has loaded, I then need to grab them with jQuery to send to the new page. If there is a better way to do this, I am open to it.

Comment: Even if this does not directly resolve your problem: please be warned that your queries are highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: "Is it a problem with chaining ajax commands?" - what have you tried to check for this cause? The code from `view_appraisal.php` doesn't even look like it could work in any way, as you can't mix PHP and JS directly

Comment: @NicoHaase - I know I still need to do changes for SQLinjection, I'm just trying to get it to work first. I've done tests at multiple points to try to figure out where the break is. There are no errors being given. If I load view_appraisal with the variables I'm trying to send through ajax it works. I've put test code in the view_appraisals page to make sure update_appraisals ajax is loading it, that works. The reason I need the 3rd page is because view_ grabs info through php, js calculates it. I need that info to automatically update the database when the request comes from the update_ page.